# Making cocoa application scriptable

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, applescript, cocoa-scripting

I am new to cocoa development
Can any one please tell me how I can make my cocoa application scriptable.
I want my application to perform certain actions,in response to scripts. I could not find easy guide or help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Developer Library - Introduction to Cocoa Scripting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_intro/SAppsIntro.html)

Comment: I have gone through this, but this involves lot of reading. Is there a help which points out what exactly to do.